# UDP Broadcasting not working

Tags: java, udp, netty, nio

My Requirement is to broadcast a UDP message to all connected client from  the server.

I am using netty 4.x.x for client server implementation. I am not I am not able to broadcast the message to all connected client.

**Server code**

```
public class UDPServer {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName());

    private final ServerConfig conf;

    /*
     * Constructor of Server class 
     */
    public UDPServer(ServerConfig conf) {
        this.conf = conf;


    public void run() throws Exception {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {


        EventLoopGroup udpGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {

            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(udpGroup)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)                    
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<DatagramChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(DatagramChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast("udpDecoder", new MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket>() {

                                @Override
                                protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
                                    out.add(msg.content());
                                    msg.retain();
                                }
                            });
                            p.addLast("handler", new UDServerPHandler());
                            p.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(65535, 2, 2));
                        }
                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true);

          //  b.bind(9998).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
              b.bind(9998).channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            udpGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method to run the class
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new UDPServer(new ServerConfig()).run();
    }

}
```

**Server Handler**

```
package com.quantotrade.shamse.udp;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

import java.util.Random;

public class UDServerPHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static final String[] quotes = {
        "ONE",
        "TWO",
        "THREE",
        "FOUR",
    };

    private static String nextQuote() {
        int quoteId;
        synchronized (random) {
            quoteId = random.nextInt(quotes.length);
        }
        return quotes[quoteId];
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
        //System.err.println(packet.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        //if ("Quote".equals(packet.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8))) {
          //  ctx.write(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Quote" + nextQuote(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8), packet.sender()));
            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Quote" + nextQuote(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8), packet.sender()));

        //}
    }



    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
public class UDPClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

    //private final EventExecutor executor = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    //private final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup();

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
        String response = msg.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        if (response.startsWith("Quote")) {
            System.out.println("Quote:" + response.substring(5));
            //ctx.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Quote", CharsetUtil.UTF_8), msg.sender()));
           // channels.add(ctx.channel());
        }
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: Can you identify the problem more than "it won't work"?

Comment: @user_ABCD: Why not answering the question rather popping up a new one?

Comment: For UDP server, you don't need separate eventloop groups for server/child channels.Where did you set option for broadcast? OS first need to join your interface to broadcast group to be able to use it (IGMP). Also, there is no such thing as "connected client" in UDP.